# How to access the camera feature in chrome latest version using http(insecure access)?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I want to access the camera feature in chrome browser using HTTP.

Before that am using getUserMedia() for access the camera feature in chrome but it shows an error message.It working fine in chrome 41.0 version

"getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details."

How can i access the camera feature in HTTP protocol in Google Chrome latest version

Comment: Um, the error says you can't... Check the link. SSL certs are free now though: https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: Actually from `http://localhost` you can circumvent this.

Comment: Thank you Kaiido.. After i converting into localhost it's working fine..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the device camera means you can use html input file like

`<input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture>`.

Comment: i think it's used for get the image from local system.

Comment: We added a attribute capture to access a device camera

Comment: This is called the HTMLMediaCaptureAPI and is different from GUM. You can't get a stream from MediaCaptureAPI, it's only supported by some os, (mostly mobile ones) and has been removed from standards tracks (never gone higher than candidate btw)